# Lost My Ubuntu Partition

Tags: dual-boot, data-recovery

I had my laptop dual-booting Windows and Ubuntu for near two years now. Today, I turned it on, and my Ubuntu partition was gone! Usually it asks me at the start which partition I want to choose. Now it goes straight to Windows. Do you guys know if there is anyway to recover it? I had all my work there!

Thanks!

EDIT:

I booted from the usb and I still have everything, fortunately. Do you guys know how can I access Ubuntu again without the usb?

Comment: See if your partition is still there in disk management. There should also be a dedicated key to choose which OS you want to boot ( in my case F11 for my HP Envy). Or boot from the usb device you used to install Ubuntu and choose 'try Ubuntu'. Then see if the partition is still there.

Comment: Boot from an Ubuntu installation USB using the **Try Ubuntu** option. Try to access your Ubuntu partition from there. Then update this question. You may use the app gparted from the live USB.

Comment: @HomerSimpson it still has the partition but it says it is 100% free. I tried the F11 key (I also own a HP Envy) but it opens a blue menu with the options "Continue", "Use a device", "Problem Resolution" and "Turn Off". Unfortunately I don't have the usb device with me now.

Comment: @user68186 ok, I don't have the usb I used but I can use another right?

Comment: You can always try [Testdisk](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step) from a LiveCD / USB to see if it can recover the last partition, or if it can see any you might be able to browse through your files and recover them to another location.

Comment: Right. You can download the ISO file from the official site. They also have instructions for how to put the ISO into the USB from within Windows to make it bootable.

Comment: I'll try it. Thank you so much!

Comment: Temporarily install **boot repair** while running Ubuntu from the USB. Run the app and click the big **Recommended Repair** button. Before you to this, [read the documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair).

Comment: @user68186 yes, it does! The boot repair instructions did not work also, but I ended up just changing the boot order as he did. Thank you so much! Just one more thing, do you have any insight of why this happened?

Comment: Sometimes a Windows update changes the boot process and makes Windows the default. I guess that's what happened.